# How To Multiply Two GridView Columns into One

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewcolumn, visual-studio-2010

I want to be able to input a value into a quantity textbox, then:

- Multiply that value with its "Unit Square Foot" and store the result into "Subtotal"
- Sum each subtotal and store the result into "Total"

This is what I have so far:

```
           <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridViewBuildOfficeSpace" AllowPaging="false" 
                AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
                AutoGenerateEditButton="false" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" 
               onrowdatabound="gridViewBuildOfficeSpace_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Dimensions" HeaderText="Dimensions" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Square Foot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="unitSquareFootLabel" Text='<%# Eval("UnitSquareFoot") %>'  />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="gridviewQuantityItem" runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" Text="Total Size: " runat="server" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SubTotal">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="gridViewItemSubTotal"  runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="totalSizeDisplayLabel" runat="server" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
        protected void gridViewBuildOfficeSpace_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < gridViewBuildOfficeSpace.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            gridViewBuildOfficeSpace.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(gridViewBuildOfficeSpace.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text)*Convert.ToDouble(gridViewBuildOfficeSpace.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text)); 
        }
    }
```

I tried using within the TextBox, OnTextChanged and then tried to find the controls relevant to turn them into ints and multiply them and display the value into the label but I either get null references regarding the unitSquareFootLabel.

But with the code behind above I get input string is not in the correct format.

How would I do this?

Comment: Gonna need more details bruh. Please describe the errors you are getting, which questions have you looked at (and why they failed).

Comment: Is it me, or the Title of the Question is misleading. Multiply Two Grids into One? So that means Two Grid? Doesn't make any difference does it?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Do the calculations client-side with jQuery or javascript
2. Do them on the backend with c# (involves refreshing the page)

I'd recommend the first option. Here is an example:
So the gridview needs to be modified a little. I added some css class names that can be easily referenced with JS and jQuery:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridViewBuildOfficeSpace" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SIZE" HeaderText="Size" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DIMENSIONS" HeaderText="Dimensions" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Square Foot">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="unitSquareFootLabel" Text='<%# Eval("SQFOOT") %>'  />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="unitSquareFoot" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="gridviewQuantityItem" runat="server" onblur="calculate()"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" Text="Total Size: " runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SubTotal">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="gridViewItemSubTotal"  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="SubTotal" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="totalSizeDisplayLabel" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then at the bottom of the page, before the closing body tag, add this js:

```
<script>
    function calculate() {
        //get the gridview
        gv = $('#gridViewBuildOfficeSpace');
        //Find the number of rows in the grid
        var rowCount = gv.find('tr').length;

        //Iterate through each row looking for the input boxes (This section is for the ROW totals)
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        //Iterate through each text box
            var row = gv.find("tr:eq(" + i + ")");
            //Find the input text field
            row.find(":input[type=text]").each(function () {
                //Get the quantity value
                quantity = $(this).val();
                //Get the sqfoot
                sqfoot = row.find("[class$='unitSquareFoot']").text();
                //Add the text to the subtotal field
                row.find("[class$='SubTotal']").text(quantity * sqfoot);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This assumes you add a reference to jQuery for it to work...

Comment: I tried this method and none of the columns change when i type in a number in the quantity, when it came to the script i made it of type "text/javascript" and "text/jscript" on separate occasions with no job

Comment: Have you added a reference to jQuery?

Comment: Add this line after your `<title></title>` tag - `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. The gridview example I added shouldnt be copy/pasted, you will need to modify it a little for your scenario. Please accept the answer if it helped.